# WPF: Listbox custom items unable to auto size

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a listbox with dynamically added items which are custom user controls (PriceGroupControl).

I am trying to resize that custom user control based on the size of the parent, but it always has a fixed size not related to the size of the listboxitem as far as I can see and resizing just clips the control.
I am using a similar control in a grid and that resizes perfectly.

My page has a grid, the first row has a combobox, the second has the custom control that resizes and the third row has a scrollviewer with a listbox in it. Since the listbox items are quite large and dynamically added, I use the scrollviewer.
The reason why I use a listbox is that, because based on the selected item, the content of the custom control on the second row of the grid is updated.

In XAML:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>        
            <StackPanel Margin="12" Grid.Row="0">
                <ComboBox Name="comboBoxPriceGroups" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" 
                   SelectedValuePath="GroupName"   
                 Width="250" SelectionChanged="comboBoxPriceGroups_SelectionChanged">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupDescription}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>         
            </StackPanel>
            <Frame x:Name="ModPriceFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10"/>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListBox x:Name="PriceListBox" Margin="10" Background="{StaticResource BackgroundLightBrush}" BorderThickness="0" SelectionChanged="PriceList_SelectionChanged"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The way I bound my listbox content to the listbox is the following:

```
List<PriceGroupControl> priceGroupControls = new List<PriceGroupControl>(); 
foreach (GroupDetail detail in groupDetails)
 {
      priceGroupControls.Add(new PriceGroupControl(detail.GroupName, detail.GroupDetailDescription));
 }

 PriceListBox.ItemsSource = priceGroupControls;
```

I have tried the following:

- listbox: width set to auto in XAML, width = double.NaN code behind
- my custom control: horizontalAlignment = stretch, horizontalContentAlignment = stretch, width = double.NaN.
- bind a list of listboxitems with each listboxitem having a pricegroupcontrol.

If I put an actual number e.g. 1000 as the minimum width of pricegroupcontrol, it sizes to this width and looks more normal (now everything is cramped together in the minimum space needed), but obviously doesn't resize with the screen.

I am fairly new to WPF, so maybe I am missing the obvious.
I have used the live visual tree to get an idea which part is causing the issue and this seems to indicate that it is the PriceGroupControl that is too small, while the listbox is the size of the screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is already a ScrollViewer in the default ListBox Template. No need to put it into another one. Just set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` on the ListBox as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the ScrollViewer. This is nicer than my solution for scrolling